# Elasticsearch analyzer doesn't replace the apostophes (')

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-analyzers

Using Elasticsearch v7.0
This is the analyzer I've implemented (`http://phoenyx2:9200/search_dev/_settings?pretty=true`):

```
{
    "search_dev": {
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "refresh_interval": "30s",
                "number_of_shards": "1",
                "provided_name": "search_dev",
                "creation_date": "1558444846417",
                "analysis": {
                    "analyzer": {
                        "my_standard": {
                            "filter": [
                                "lowercase"
                            ],
                            "char_filter": [
                                "my_char_filter"
                            ],
                            "tokenizer": "standard"
                        }
                    },
                    "char_filter": {
                        "my_char_filter": {
                            "type": "mapping",
                            "mappings": [
                                "' => "
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "hYz0ZlWFTDKearW1rpx8lw",
                "version": {
                    "created": "7000099"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've recreated the whole index, and there is still no change in the analasis.
I've also run this : url (`phoenyx2:9200/search_dev/_analyze`)

```
{
    "analyzer":"my_standard",
    "field":"stakeholderName",
    "text": "test't"
}
```

Reply was:

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "test't",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 6,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

I was hoping the the returned token would be "`testt`"

Comment: I don't find any thing wrong with this. I even tried to replicate using the settings you mentioned. Its working fine.

Comment: @NishantSaini which version are you using :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you re-create an index its not enough to define a new analyzer in the setting.

You also have to specify in the mapping which fields use what analyzer, for example:

```
   "mappings":{
       "properties":{
          "stakeholderName": {
             "type":"text",
             "analyzer":"my_analyzer", 
         },
      }
   }
```

You're mapping (probably) looks like:

```
   "mappings":{
       "properties":{
          "stakeholderName": {
             "type":"text",
         },
      }
   }
```

Basicaly if you run your "analyze" test again and drop the field:

```
{
    "analyzer":"my_standard",
    "text": "test't"
}
```

You'll get:

```
{
  "token": "testt",
  "start_offset": 0,
  "end_offset": 6,
  "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
  "position": 0
}
```

As you expect it, so bad news buddy but you have to re-index all your data again and this time specify in the mapping which analyzer you want to be used for each field, otherwise elastic will default to their standard analyzer every time.

Comment: How do I add mappings?  
Right now simply POJO data to it from Java. :)
(Can you add the curl command on your example)

Comment: Easiest way is to specify it when you create the index, however you can use [put mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) which is "adds" a new field to an empty index.

Comment: I've only added empty index'es, I'll try looking it up. Thanks a lot!